# CASTING to INT Problem in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am running into an error with a stored procedure I'm trying to run in SQL Server. Part of my procedure looks like this:

```
    WHERE 
        RM20101.CUSTNMBR NOT LIKE ('CR0002%')
        AND RM20101.VOIDSTTS != 1
        AND CAST(REPLACE(LEFT( RM20101.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', RM20101.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '') AS INT) = 481492) a
WHERE 
    a.DocumentAmount != 0
```

The `CAST` I'm doing here results in this error:

> The conversion of the varchar value '02570000096' overflowed an int column.

So I tried using `BIGINT` instead, like so:

```
    WHERE 
        RM20101.CUSTNMBR NOT LIKE ('CR0002%')
        AND RM20101.VOIDSTTS != 1
        AND CAST(REPLACE(LEFT( RM20101.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', RM20101.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '') AS BIGINT) = 481492) a
WHERE 
    a.DocumentAmount != 0
```

But that produces this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

How can I handle this in a way that won't error out?

Comment: Minor tip, if you're running that replace just to get rid of a leading '-', make it charindex+1 instead

Comment: That's a good tip. What would that syntax look like in the above example?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it's LEFT/trailing dash - would be charindex-1

Comment: @Muirik I see that you deleted your question.  Perhaps the answer below will help

Answer (score 1):

One or more of your rows contains a value that doesn't convert. Consider using [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead or filter the bad rows out with a where clause

You could also consider not converting the data at all and just look for `WHERE column LIKE '481492-%'` or similar. Not converting means you have more chance of using an index

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted your last question.

I suspect you have some bogus or unanticipated data in DOCNUMBR

If you use try_convert(), it will return a NULL value rather than throwing an error

```
Declare @YourTable table (DOCNUMBR varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('004000009123-000')
,('02570000096-000')
,('BOGUS-STRING')
,('BOGUS')
,(null)


Select *
      ,AsAnInt = try_convert(bigint,left(DOCNUMBR,charindex('-',DOCNUMBR+'-')-1))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
DOCNUMBR            AsAnInt
004000009123-000    4000009123
02570000096-000     2570000096
BOGUS-STRING        NULL         -- Fails to Convert but no error
BOGUS               NULL         -- Fails to Convert but no error
NULL                NULL         -- Fails to Convert but no error
```

**To find the Trouble Records**

```
Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where try_convert(bigint,left(DOCNUMBR,charindex('-',DOCNUMBR+'-')-1)) is null
```

**Returns**

```
DOCNUMBR
BOGUS-STRING
BOGUS
NULL
```